# Prevent duplication data in two template table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have some question about Query duplication data in two template table.

For example, I have two template table(ListA,ListB)

ListA Contain:

```
ID        FirstName 
123       Peter
456       Ben
789       Eric
```

List B:

```
ID      FirstName 
123     Peter
888     Jack
999     Mary
```

When generating both List A and List B, if FirstName, ID has both appear , How to do that  details of such FirstName, ID will be excluded from List B and show in List A only (avoid duplication).
Thanks!

```
Alter proc [dbo].xxxxx

@List varchar(5)

as
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

CREATE TABLE #Result
(
iList char(1),
[ID] nvarchar(100),
[FirstName] nvarchar(100),
)

if @iList like '%A%'
BEGIN
insert into #Result
Select 
iList = 'A',
[ID] = ab.[ID],
FirstName = ab.[FirstName]
from xxxx
end


if @iList like '%B%'
BEGIN
insert into #Result
Select 
iList = 'B',
[ID] = ab.[ID],
FirstName = ab.[FirstName]
from xxxx
end


    select * from #Result

end
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Ms server and Ssrs report.thanks

Comment: What results do you want?

Answer (score 1):

> How to do that details of such FirstName, ID will be excluded from List B and show in List A only (avoid duplication)

If you want to remove rows from `b`, you can use `not exists`:

```
select b.*
from b
where not exists (select 1 from a where b.id = a.id);
```

Comment: Hello Gordon, finally , i modify  query : if @iList like '%B%'
BEGIN
insert into #Result
Select 
iList = 'B',
[ID] = ab.[ID],
FirstName = ab.[FirstName]
from xxxx where not exists (select 1 from #Result where b.id = a.id);
end  How can I compare two fields of same temp table... Do you have any advise?thanks!

Comment: @ericso . . . I would suggest that you ask a *new* question.  Provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to accomplish.  Be sure the explanation matches the data.